# Does "speak in a low voice" refer to volume/loudness or to pitch?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

Does the *low* in

> Speak in a *low* voice!
>
> He said in a *low* voice.

refer to the *volume*/*loudness* or to the *pitch*? Does it mean *quiet*, or *low-frequency*?

EDIT: After understanding from your answers that the meaning is ambiguous (it may apparently mean either the first or the second or both), and after reading some answers to [Please "Mute your voice"!](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/178266/73094) suggesting "*lower* your voice" as a request to speak *more quietly*, I am adding a related question:

Is the meaning of

> *Lower* your voice!

also ambiguous, or does *this particular* phrase refer unambiguously to loudness?

Comment: That reminded me of a little kid I used to know.  At age three or four he totally couldn't whisper.  He would try but everything came out loud.  I can remember once in a store him trying to whisper to his mom... "Mom, why is that lady so fat?"  It's very funny now, not so much at the time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***[low](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/low?q=low)***

> (Of a sound or voice) not loud or high:
>   *keep the volume very low
>
>   his low, husky voice*

It has, therefore, **both** the meanings.
The same dictionary defines *[husky](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/husky?q=husky)* thus:

> 1 (Of a voice or utterance) sounding low-pitched and slightly hoarse:
>   *his voice became a husky, erotic whisper*

A *low* voice **can** be loud! (click 'More example sentences' in the *low* entry to open)

> *His voice was low and loud, like a volcanic eruption sounds from inside the volcano.*

---

[EDIT]
By the same token, ***lower your voice*** would also be ambiguous. However, there would hardly be an occasion to ask someone to reduce the **frequency** rather than the **amplitude**, other than maybe at an audition/ recording session.

Comment: It's certainly not necessarily ***both at the same time***, as your final example shows. And there are plenty of written instances of both [*"low and quiet voice"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22low+and+quiet+voice%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) ***and*** [*"low but loud voice"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22low+but+loud+voice%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl).

Comment: Vin Diesel has a low voice: Vin Diesel on CO2 sounds like a diesel (hah!) generator, on Helium a normal person; his voice is low regardless of the volume he speaks. I think it would be clearer if you edited to make it more obvious the answer is essentially 'both or either, depending on context.'

Comment: I think it's usually *either* quiet or deep, not *both*. Without further context, I'd assume *quiet* was the intent.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The pitfalls of a language! Edited to show what I really meant.

Comment: @Kris: "there would hardly be an occasion to ask someone to reduce the frequency rather than the amplitude" - you don't have small kids, do you? :)

Comment: @HonzaZidek Lol! You're right. My first grandchild is only days old now, gotta see.

Comment: @Kris: I have been asking my youngest daughter to reduce her voice frequency several times a day :)

Answer (score 4):

The most common sense would be for "low voice" to mean low levels of loudness.

The most common way to ask for a low pitch would be to ask for a "deep voice"

Answer (score 2):

It depends entirely on context. "Darth Vader has a low voice." or 
 "Why are you speaking in such a low voice?" 
 "Because my throat is sore."

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. The usual phrase is, "Darth Vader has a *deep* voice".   I personally haven't heard 'low voice' used that way. Edit: I've just noticed that Oldcat makes that point.